# Well-ordered subsets of directed sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory

In general, can we always find a well-ordered cofinal subset of any given directed set?

In this case, is there any specific reference?

Comment: On a bit of a tangent, there are examples of subsets of topological spaces which are closed under all limits of nets indexed by well-ordered sets, but which are not closed subsets overall (and therefore not closed under all limits of nets indexed by directed sets).

Comment: Related, but much more general, is the theory of *cofinal types* of directed sets. See for instance [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1985-290-02/S0002-9947-1985-0792822-9/S0002-9947-1985-0792822-9.pdf) or [here](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/zr/25/zrn25p53-80.pdf)

Answer (score 7):

Let $X$ be any uncountable set and let $F$ be the set of finite subsets of $X$, ordered by inclusion.  Then $F$ is directed, but it has no cofinal well-ordered subset. Indeed, any totally ordered subset $C\subseteq F$ must be countable (it has at most one element of each finite cardinality), and so $\bigcup C$ is countable and thus not all of $X$, so $C$ cannot be cofinal in $F$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\kappa=(2^{\aleph_0})^+$ and consider $[\kappa]^{<\omega}$, a set of all finite subsets of $\kappa$. Then $([\kappa]^{<\omega},\subseteq)$ is a directed set, but there is no well-ordered cofinal subset: Suppose that there is a cofinal $C\subseteq[\kappa]^{<\omega}$. For each $\xi\in \kappa$, choose the $\subseteq$-least element $a_\xi\in C$ such that $\xi\in a_\xi$.

If there is $a\in C$ and there are infinitely many $\xi\in\kappa$ such that $a_\xi=a$, then $a$ is infinite, a contradiction. Hence for each $a\in C$ there are finitely many $\xi\in\kappa$ such that $a_\xi =a$. Hence we can fix a set $X\subseteq \kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$ such that the map $\xi\mapsto a_\xi$ restricted to $X$ is one-to-one.

Now consider the coloring $f\colon [X]^2\to 2$ given by
$$f(\{\eta,\xi\})=0 \iff \eta<\xi\ \land\ a_\eta\subsetneq a_\xi,$$
and
$$f(\{\eta,\xi\})=1 \iff \eta<\xi\ \land\ a_\eta\supsetneq a_\xi.$$

Now apply the Erdős–Rado theorem $\kappa\to(\omega_1)^2_\omega$ to get an $f$-homogeneous set $Y\subseteq X$ of cardinality $\omega_1$. If $Y=\{\alpha_\xi\mid \xi\in\omega_1\}$, then $\langle a_{\alpha_\xi}\mid \xi\in\omega_1\rangle$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing under $\subsetneq$, which is contradictory in either directions.

Note that you can get a desired cofinal set if the directed set is linear. It follows from a typical Zorn's lemma argument (Consider the collection of all subsets of the directed set that is well-ordered, and take the maximal well-ordered set.)